# Autofilter error (looking in wrong columns)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using if statements and .autofilter to search in different columns depending on what the first two digits are from a text file I'm having it read from. My problem is it searches through the corresponding columns for the first line of data in the text file and then searches those same columns every time it runs through the loop. This is what I have:

```
Dim myFile As String

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

Open myFile For Input As #1

Dim source As String
Dim destination As Range

Dim rowNum As Long

Set destination = Sheets("SHOULDER").Range("A2")

Do Until EOF(1)

    Line Input #1, source

    If Mid(source, 1, 2) = "09" Then

        With destination.Columns("B:C")
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Mid(source, 3, 4)
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Mid(source, 7, 4)
        End With

        rowNum = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        Cells(rowNum, 8).Value = Mid(source, 23, 2) & " " & Mid(source, 21, 2) & " " & Mid(source, 19, 2)
        Cells(rowNum, 9).Value = Mid(source, 11, 2) & "/" & Mid(source, 13, 2) & "/" & Mid(source, 15, 4)

    ElseIf Mid(source, 1, 2) = "15" Then

        With destination.Columns("L:M")
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Mid(source, 3, 4)
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Mid(source, 7, 4)
        End With

        rowNum = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        Cells(rowNum, 18).Value = Mid(source, 23, 2) & " " & Mid(source, 21, 2) & " " & Mid(source, 19, 2)
        Cells(rowNum, 19).Value = Mid(source, 11, 2) & "/" & Mid(source, 13, 2) & "/" & Mid(source, 15, 4)

    ElseIf Mid(source, 1, 2) = "23" Then

        With destination.Columns("V:W")
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Mid(source, 3, 4)
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Mid(source, 7, 4)
        End With

        rowNum = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        Cells(rowNum, 28).Value = Mid(source, 23, 2) & " " & Mid(source, 21, 2) & " " & Mid(source, 19, 2)
        Cells(rowNum, 29).Value = Mid(source, 11, 2) & "/" & Mid(source, 13, 2) & "/" & Mid(source, 15, 4)

    End If
Loop
    Selection.AutoFilter
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the applied [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) before looping into the next line read to *source*. You are cancelling the applied .AutoFilter **outside** the loop, not inside the loop.

```
With Worksheets("SHOULDER")
    With .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp))
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, Source
            Select Case Mid(Source, 1, 2)
                Case "09"
                    .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Mid(Source, 3, 4)
                    .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=Mid(Source, 7, 4)
                Case "15"
                    .AutoFilter field:=12, Criteria1:=Mid(Source, 3, 4)
                    .AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:=Mid(Source, 7, 4)
                Case "23"
                    .AutoFilter field:=22, Criteria1:=Mid(Source, 3, 4)
                    .AutoFilter field:=23, Criteria1:=Mid(Source, 7, 4)
                Case Else
                    'do nothing
            End Select

            rowNum = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(rowNum, 28).Value = Mid(Source, 23, 2) & " " & Mid(Source, 21, 2) & " " & Mid(Source, 19, 2)
            .Cells(rowNum, 29).Value = Mid(Source, 11, 2) & "/" & Mid(Source, 13, 2) & "/" & Mid(Source, 15, 4)

            'this is what was missing - reset the .AutoFilter in prep for the next one
            If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        Loop
    End With
End With
```

I've rewritten the logic to use a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) and reduce the redundant code. It may not be entirely correct but I hope you can see where I've reset the .AutoFilter to accept the next one in the loop.